# Sync Android Studio Room Database (Kotlin) with Spreadsheet using Google Sheets API

Tags: android, kotlin, synchronization, android-room, spreadsheet

What I have:

- Android App created with Kotlin in Android Studio
- Room Database that has one table
- Created a Google Cloud Console project, activated the Sheets API and Sign-In data
- I am able to sign in to my google account in the app
- a spreadsheet in my google cloud

How can I accomplish the last step of connecting the table in room with my spreadsheet? There seem to be no up-to-date tutorials.

Thanks!

- numerous tutorials that were mostly done in Java or with outdated APIs

Comment: What have you tried so far?